# Show a message box on another computer in vbscript?

Tags: networking, vbscript

How do I show a message box on a running computer in your network in vbscript? I've searched everywhere and I'm not getting any answer.

Comment: VBScript does not provide an infrastructure for remote messaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit advanced question for VBScript, but as the WSH allow remote scripting, it's possible task for [WSHController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk7bxb0d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Of course it require proper configuration and this [article](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-script-host-wsh/rem-getting-the-wshcontroller-object-to-work-23607) show some of the steps to setup this object, [Microsoft's Windows Script 5.6 documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764) offer more details.

There's some limitations that not allow UI interaction (like MsgBox, InputBox, etc) in remote scripts, but this can be *cheated* by creating another script with `FileSystemObject`.

You'll need 2 scripts, one that you run from your controller machine (I'll name it *RemoteScript.vbs*) and second that you'll copy to the target machine (*Messenger.wsf*). I'll post a whole code in one block here, but you'll need to copy each part in separate file.

```
REM ----------- RemoteScript.vbs code start here -------------

Const WshFinished = 2

Dim Controller, RemoteScript, RemoteServer
RemoteServer = "\\server_name"

Set Controller = WScript.CreateObject("WSHController")
Set RemoteScript = Controller.CreateScript("Messenger.wsf", RemoteServer)

WScript.ConnectObject RemoteScript, "WSH_"
RemoteScript.Execute

Do While RemoteScript.Status <> WshFinished 
    WScript.Sleep 200
Loop

WScript.DisconnectObject RemoteScript

Sub WSH_Error
    With RemoteScript.Error
        WScript.Echo "Error " & _
        CStr(Hex(.Number)) & " - Line: " & .Line & _
        ", Char: " & .Character & vbCrLf & _
        "Description: " & .Description
    End With
    WScript.Quit -1
End Sub

Function WSH_End()
    MsgBox "wshRemote End Event fired"
End Function

Function WSH_Start()
    MsgBox "wshRemote Start Event fired"
End Function

REM ----------- RemoteScript.vbs code end here ---------------

REM ----------- Messenger.wsf code start here ----------------

<package>
  <job>
    <script language="VBScript">
      tmpFile = "c:\_tmp711a.vbs"
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set fout = fso.CreateTextFile(tmpFile, true)
      fout.WriteLine "MsgBox ""Remote Hello"", 0, ""Example"" "
      fout.Close
      WScript.Sleep 100
      Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      shell.Run "wscript " & tmpFile, 1, True
      If fso.FileExists(tmpFile) Then fso.DeleteFile(tmpFile)
    </script>
  </job>
</package>

REM ----------- Messenger.wsf code end here ----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following Windows commands:

- [`net send`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true) (not supported on Windows Vista and above; requires the Messenger service to be running)
- [`msg`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771903%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (for Terminal Server users only)

You can execute these commands from VBScript using [`WshShell.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), for example:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("net send computername Hello, world!")
```

Comment: `net send` stopped working in 2004 when SP2 for Windows XP disabled the messenger service by default. The service was removed entirely in Windows Vista.